# Find the value m in modular

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can we find m in this modular?

$$aa^{-1}  \equiv 1\mod\ m 
$$

$$where\ a ,a^{-1} are\ known$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! $m$ is divisor of $aa^{-1}-1$, that's all we can say.

Comment: No, because the statement is true for all non-zero integers m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose integer values are specified for $a,a^{-1}$.

To be less confusing, let $b = a^{-1}$.

Then 
$$ab\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;m) \iff\ m\mid (ab-1)$$

so any integer divisor of $ab-1$ qualifies as a value of $m$.

For example, let $a=7,\;a^{-1}=4$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&7^{-1}\equiv 4\;(\text{mod}\;m)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&28 \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;m)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&m\mid 27\\[4pt]
\iff\;&m\in\{\pm 1,\pm 3,\pm 9,\pm 27\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: it means that not only one integer ?

Comment: Right. There are choices. Any integer divisor of $ab-1$ will qualify as a value of $m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)